# How to fetch text value dynamically when clicked on it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a **DJANGO** app and want to get the values of text in **JAVASCRIPT** when it gets selected but getting undefined instead.

my code:

```
<div class="askedDiv">
  {% for i in recentlyUsed %}
    <p onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">{{i}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

in js:

```
function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
  console.log(x)
}
```

but **in console i'm getting undefined**.

How can I get different text name, when it is selected from recentlyUsed list.

Comment: `value` is for input elements. You want to get the `textContent`. Furthermore, if you need a button than please use a `<button>` element

Comment: Additionally, JS can't determine, from which element you actually want to get the content, it'll always select the first found element with the passed `id`. Ids are supposed to be unique within the document. Take a look at [Mouse Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent), that will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Reyno, thanks for reply . I made changes which you said, but its returning only first element from the list on clicking of another values from list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text, then simply pass the desired value to the function as an argument, no need to use DOM methods to get it:

```
<p onclick="myFunction('{{i}}')" >{{i}}</p>
```

```
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log(x)
}
```

And if you still need the element, you can pass it too:

```
<p onclick="myFunction('{{i}}', this)" >{{i}}</p>
```

```
function myFunction(x, el) {
  console.log(x, el);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this approach on my local. You can do the one below

```js
// option 1: pass the event object so function is reusable and can be applied to any element

function getValue(e) {
  const value = e.target.innerText; // if you want to get the text value
  // const value = e.target.innerHTML; // if you want to get the markup value
  
  console.log(value);
}

// option 2: use your current code but fix to that paragraph only basd on id selector

function getValue2() {
   const value = document.getElementById('my-btn').innerText;
   
   console.log(value);
}


// option 3: use the document

// as an alternative, you can bind your click even to the document to dynamically get the value of any element in your document
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const value = e.target?.value || e.target.innerText;
  
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p onclick="getValue(event)">Option 1</p>
</div>


<div>
  <p onclick="getValue2()" id="my-btn">Option 2</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Option 3</p>
</div>
```

Additional Information:
The reason why your code is not working is because the paragraph element doesn't have a value property. Value property only works for inputs since their property exists to set/get the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`html`

```
<div class="askedDiv">
  {% for i in recentlyUsed %}
    <p onclick="funName(this)">{{i}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`Js`

```
function funName(e) {
  console.log($(e).text());
}
```